# Multiline codec in Logstash 5.2.0 not working

Tags: logstash

The following codec config in Logstash in never detecting a new line:

```
input { 
    file {
        path => "c:\temp\log5.log"
        type => "log4net"
        codec => multiline {
          pattern => "^hello"
          negate => true
          what => previous
           }
      }
}
```

Please can someone confirm if my interpretation of the above config is correct:

> If a line does not begin with the text "hello" then merge that line
>   with the previous line. Conversely if a line begins with the text
>   "hello" treat is as the start of a new log event.

With the above config, Logstash never detects a new line in my log file even though I have a few lines starting with "hello". Any ideas what the problem may be?

**EDIT:**

```
input { 
  file { 
    path => "//22.149.166.241/GatewayUnsecure/Log_2016.03.22_22.log"
    start_position => "beginning" 
    type => "log4net" 
    codec => multiline { 
      pattern => "^%{YEAR}[/-]%{MONTHNUM}[/-]%{MONTHDAY}" 
      negate => true 
      what => previous 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Log sample:

```
2016-03-22 22:00:07,768 [3] INFO AbCap.Cerberus [(null)] - Cerberus 'Cerberus Service Hosting - Unsecure', ('Local'), version 1.0.0.0, host 'WinService' 2016-03-22 22:00:07,783 [7] INFO AbCap.Cerberus [(null)] - Starting 'Cerberus Service Hosting - Unsecure' on JHBDSM020000273 in Local. 2016-03-22 22:00:07,783 [7] DEBUG AbCap.Cerberus [(null)] - Starting: WcfHostWorker 2016-03-22 22:00:07,783 [7] INFO AbCap.Cerberus [(null)] - is opening
```

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, could you add a some sample logs as they appear in the input file? that may allow us to discern the cause of your issue

Comment: Thanks Will!
Actual logstash input config (file sample in next comment):
    input { 
        file {
            path =>     "//22.149.166.241/GatewayUnsecure/Log_2016.03.22_22.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
  type => "log4net"
            codec => multiline {
           pattern => "^%{YEAR}[/-]%{MONTHNUM}[/-]%{MONTHDAY} "
         negate => true
       what => previous
               }
      }
}

Comment: 2016-03-22 22:00:07,768 [3] INFO  AbCap.Cerberus [(null)] - Cerberus 'Cerberus Service Hosting - Unsecure', ('Local'), version 1.0.0.0, host 'WinService'
2016-03-22 22:00:07,783 [7] INFO  AbCap.Cerberus [(null)] - Starting 'Cerberus Service Hosting - Unsecure' on JHBDSM020000273 in Local.
2016-03-22 22:00:07,783 [7] DEBUG AbCap.Cerberus [(null)] - Starting: WcfHostWorker
2016-03-22 22:00:07,783 [7] INFO  AbCap.Cerberus [(null)] - is opening.

Comment: Hey Ricardo, I edited your config/log example into the question, but im not sure how the log is formatted in the file, could you update that?

Comment: I tested your multiline codec and it seems to work fine, I've found a [reference to a strange bug where `start_position => "beginning"` does not work alongside multiline](https://gist.github.com/junxy/206150421f568e65a2a2b006cb8811e9). Could you try this without the `start_position`? Either deleting your sincedb or pointing the input plugin at a new sincedb will read the file from the beginning anyway

Comment: Thanks again Will!
I have a bit of egg on my face as I figured out what was going on - my logfile was encoded in *UCS-2 Big Endian* which naturally caused my patterns in the code and grok filter to fail as the default encoding used by the multiline codec is UTF-8! So I changed the encoding to `UCS-2BE` and all worked as expected. Thanks @WillBarnwell for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it got resolved, you should add that as an answer to this question so that the next person to run across this issue knows how you solved it